# AJAX call doesn't seem to POST any data

Tags: php, json, ajax, codeigniter, post

Im trying to send data to a codeigniter function to validate all fields are filled and the email is OK.
Yet it seems like the ajax call isn't sending anything at all..

I have tried changing the order, and how many values are send to the function, yet none seem to change the fact that it always gives a empty string in response.

NOTE: i also tried replacing the "click" for submit.

ajax code:

```
$('#appointment_form_submit').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    $.ajax({
        url: 'afspraken/appointment_validation',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            respondee_name: $('#InputName').val(), 
            respondee_email: $('#InputEmail').val(),
            respondee_phone: $('#InputTel').val(),
            respondee_date: $('#startDate').val(),
            respondee_time: $('#select_timestamp').val(),
            respondee_appointment: $('#select_appointment').val()
        },
        success: function(data) {
            // check if data is empty
            if(data.trim() == ""){
                console.log('no errors');
            } else {
                console.log(data);
                // get data
                var err = JSON.parse(data);
                $('#errors_display_respondee_name').html(err.respondee_name_error);
                $('#errors_display_respondee_email').html(err.respondee_email_error);
                $('#errors_display_respondee_phone').html(err.respondee_phone_error);
                $('#errors_display_respondee_date').html(err.respondee_date_error);
                $('#errors_display_respondee_time').html(err.respondee_time_error);
                $('#errors_display_respondee_appointment').html(err.respondee_appointment_error);
            }
        },
        error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log(XMLHttpRequest.responseText);
            console.log(textStatus);
            console.log(errorThrown);
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

Codeigniter function:

```
function appointment_validation(){
    // set validation rule
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('respondee_name', 'Naam', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('respondee_email', 'E-mailadres', 'trim|required|valid_email');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('respondee_phone', 'Telefoonnummer', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('respondee_date', 'Datum', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('respondee_time', 'Tijd', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('respondee_appointment', 'Hoe', 'required');
    // fun validation
    if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE){
        // validation fails
        $vals = [
            'error' => true,
            'respondee_name_error' => form_error('respondee_gender'),
            'respondee_email_error' => form_error('respondee_firstName'),
            'respondee_phone_error' => form_error('respondee_lastName'),
            'respondee_date_error' => form_error('respondee_emailAddress'),
            'respondee_time_error' => form_error('respondee_emailAddress'),
            'respondee_appointment_error' => form_error('respondee_emailAddress')
        ];
        echo json_encode($vals);
    }
}
```

Comment: *"it seems like the ajax call isn't sending anything"* - What specifically brings you to this conclusion?  When you debug this, what specifically happens?  Are there any errors at all on the browser's debugging console?  In the browser's debugging tools, on the network tab, is the AJAX request made?  What is the server's response?  In the browser's script debugger, is the even handler invoked at all?

Comment: Well when one of the values is empty, it should be returning something. That issue im having is that it isn't returning anything at all (i tried the console and alert).

Comment: *"i tried the console and alert"* - Did you examine the network requests/responses in the browser's debugging tools?  That's the source of truth for the data being sent and received, not alerts.

Comment: Please, [quit using `alert()` for troubleshooting.](http://stravid.com/en/stop-the-javascript-alert-madness/), use `console.log()` instead.

Comment: From your code it is entirely unclear what form_validation does. Does it automatically read the post? What if you do var_dump($_POST); a the first line of the appoinment validation function?